# Codeigniter userdata not available

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter for my project. I'm near end and I cannot change session "engine" now. I have captcha image for comment posting on url:

```
example.com/captcha
```

and code:

```
this->load->library('session');
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
/*
* Image generation code...
*/
$this->session->set_userdata('captcha', strtolower($word));
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Usually when I'm submitting a form I use

```
<img src="example.com/captcha" />
```

to generate image and set userdata. But this time it doesn't work. $this->session->userdata('captcha') is empty.

But if I visit image directly sessiondata is set and on next submit there is a $word which was generated on direct access of image/captcha. What could cause this?

Comment: Where is this code? In your view or controller?

Comment: @DavidNguyen in controller in function captcha

Comment: try setting it before the header?

Comment: is the image displaying properly if you call it? (not direct visit)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11891/discussion-between-user1188570-and-david-nguyen)

Comment: what happens if you var_dump $word before setting the user data? i.e. are you sure "sessions" are the problem? could be the $word var

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Image is actually generated with $word variable. And if I visit example.com/captcha directly userdata IS set.

Answer (score 0):

The image was on domain with "www" prefix, while index was on domain.com. I figure this out by setting database for sessions. I've seen there were two entries for one page visit with different session_id.