# code igniter userdata session is EMPTY on cURL CANNOT LOGIN

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, curl

I have been working on this for 2 days straight!
Still cant figure it out.
I was cURL-ing an admin website which use CodeIgniter.
I got to retrieve the captcha . I make an input text for the captcha but on POST method , we got the value of the input text and the CI Controller seem doesnt know the user data session captcha code.
I retrieve the captcha in one page and include it in a form with input texts.

```
$this->session->userdata("sess_code_login");
```

I would appreciate anyone help.
Thank u.

RESULT:

user id and password works well, but on function captcha_chk. it keeps getting error "Invalid Validation Code" because it is comparing empty captcha session with the entered captcha input.

"And if I visit example.com/captcha directly userdata IS set."

Same case - [Codeigniter userdata not avaliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806228/codeigniter-userdata-not-avaliable)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

I was looking at the session config and I see :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_sessXXXX';
```

and I renamed my cookie file on the cURL php as the same `$config['sess_cookie_name']` in the config.php

VOILA.
It had me stressed for so long and This is just so simple to fix.

Thank you